# Запись параметров команды бота через "-"

Tags: python, telebot

Я хочу сделать команду `!рандом`.
То есть, пользователь вводит, например `!рандом 1-10`, а программа выводит  `6`

Пока-что у меня получилось только так: `!рандом 1 10` (без дефиса).

```
@bot.command()
async def рандом(ctx, num1: int, num2: int)
    await ctx.send(random.randint(num1, num2))
```

Вот полный мой код:

```
from webserver import keep_alive
import discord
import json
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import time
import random
import asyncio

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!");
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command()
async def рандом(ctx, num1: int, num2: int)
    await ctx.send(random.randint(num1, num2))

@bot.command()
async def инфо(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Я первый бот от S_Smerch, я пока мало обучен. Но обещаю что буду в будущем содержать в себе много функций!')

@bot.command()
async def рандом(ctx, num, num2):
  await ctx.send(num, num2)

@bot.command()
async def пинг(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Понг!')

@bot.command()
async def бот(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Сам такой!')

@bot.command()
async def помощь(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Все команды:' '\n' '**`!помощь`**  -  вы только что прописали эту команду  :)' '\n' '**`!инфо`**  -  информация о боте' '\n' '**`!пинг`**  -  понг!' '\n' '**`!бот`**  -  вы обидете бота  :(' '\n' '**`!рандом`**  -  случайное число' '\n' '\n' 'Остались вопросы? Пиши на `TT | _#2902`!')

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Как можно сделать ввод через "-"?

P. S. Если что я пишу на [replit](https://replit.com/%7E)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте так (*если вы уверены, что пользователь введёт всё хорошо, иначе будет ошибка*):

```
@bot.command()
async def рандом(ctx, par):
    r=par.split('-')
    await ctx.send(random.randint(int(r[0]), int(r[1])))
```

У меня всё работает